# Stop a MediaElement in a ViewBox From Pixelating

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xaml, mediaelement

I have the following:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="vb" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <MediaElement x:Name="mc" />
</Viewbox>
```

To provide an option to zoom the `MediaElement`'s video to the user, I kept the `MediaElement` inside the `ViewBox` (By changing the Stretch property of the ViewBox). Doing so causes a low-res video to pixelate.

Does anyone know how can I stop the video from pixelating or implement a different method to zoom the video?

Answer (score 0):

Video will eventually pixelate at some level of zoom just like raster images will. The level of pixelation will also depend on the codec implementation and whether or not it uses hardware acceleration for rendering. MediaElement uses the codecs you have installed in your machine. May I suggest you try a ScaleTransform and see fi that helps? There's a good utorial on it here:

[UI Scaling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2007/10/05/ui-scaling-ui-zooming-with-wpf.aspx)